# AWS Device Farm- Appium Python - Order of tests

Tags: pytest, python-appium, aws-device-farm

I'm using Appium-Python with AWS Device farm. And I noticed that AWS run my tests in a random order.
Since my tests are part dependent I need to find a way to tell AWS to run my tests in a specific order.
Any ideas about how can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team. 
This seems like an old thread but I will answer so that it is helpful to everyone in future.

Device Farm parses the test in a random order. In case of Appium Python it will be the order what is received from pytest --collect-only. 
This order may change across executions.

The only way to guarantee an order right now is to wrap all the test calls in a new test which will be the only test called. Although not the prettiest solution this is the only way to achieve this today.

We are working on bringing more parity between your local environment and Device Farm in the coming weeks.